WP Создание header в блочной теме
Есть необходимость в создании прозрачной фиксированной шапки сайта в блочной теме WordPress, как на рисунке. Подскажите, пожалуйста как это сделать ?

Мои действия - это создание блочного элемента Columns и в него добавление элементов Site Title Navigation Button

Но проблема, в том что мне по сути не надо 3 колонки, мне нужно что б просто элементы занимали все допустимое пространство, а не были по 33.3% Как решить данную проблему ?
